# Which is faster: making your own database "lib" or using a third party lib

Tags: json, node.js

So I'm actually on a project that connects an IRC bot to a game server. And I needed to store the username, the player's stats, and ban expiration(if the user is banned). I'm fairly new to node.js and don't know much about node js databases,so I kind of made my own,using JSON. The JSON file is like that:

```
    {
  "Player": [
    {
      "name": "LucasTT",
      "stats": [
        103,
        1
      ],
      "banExpires": 0
    },...
```

And I made my own functions to access the database and didin't find it hard. So,is it better to use a lib like CouchDB or make my own(as I kind of did)?(Performance wise and how hard it would be to setup).

Comment: Did you really do it on your own? Did you implement transactions? Concurrency? Consistency? Safety? Efficient reading/writing? No, my friend, you did not. Use some proper database or you'll be doomed.

Comment: Sorry,I'm new to node.js. What are transactions,concurrency,consistency?  And what security holes can be there?  I don't think i left any security hole.(also,sorry if I misread your post,my primary language isn't english.).

Comment: Transactions, concurrency, consistency, etc. have nothing to do with Node.js - they are the attributes of a good database.

Comment: @LucasT. These concepts are crucial to ensure that your database works well. There's a long journey in front of you, young padawan. ;) You would have to read few books. I can't really explain everything to you, but you can start with this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID Follow inner links as well.

Comment: I really don't see any problems in the code. Can '"' be injected to the the database to break it?

Comment: @LucasT. Well, you didn't show us any code yet (and how you communicate with your custom database), so how would we know about injection? Also there are probably lots of problems with your database - you don't see them, because you don't know where to look (but that's ok, don't worry about, you'll learn eventually). Now to clarify: CouchDB is not a lib. It's a database. If you want to keep JSON structure I advise using MongoDB. It is easy to work with.

Comment: Yeah,I've been looking into MongoDB. I just need to find a good tutorial to learn it. If I do learn it, I'll probably redo my code usign MongoDB. Also, my code is here http://pastebin.com/0xvE7bZi

Answer (score 0):

If you have dozens or hundreds of users, your approach is fine. In fact, it is **better** than using a database, because it doesn't have that complexity, doesn't require another server, and usually faster.

But if your userbase will grow to thousands, and you'll want several node.js instances (or even separate servers), using a database will become an only option.

So I'd say go ahead and use JSON. You'll know when you'll need a database.

Comment: Yeah, the userbase won't grow to thousands. It's an indie game, the official IRC channel has almost always around 70 people there.